# Trouble referencing a field in power query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

So I have a table such as the one below which I call tblCodes

I want to Group By the distinct Codes, and in my aggregation get the position number(s) of each Code (in a list that I made.)

This is my code...

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblCodes"]}[Content],
    mytable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", Int64.Type}}),
    List_CODES=List.Buffer(mytable[Code]),
    Results= Table.Group(mytable, {"Code"}, {{"mylist", each List.PositionOf(List_CODES,[Code],Occurrence.All),type list}})
in
    Results
```

Now it doesn't give me any errors, but my lists are all empty.  However if I replace [Code] with a constant e.g. 1, then all my lists are filled with the positions of the value 1.  (In the example below 0,3).  So it would seem that I'm not currently able to pick up the value of [Code].  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

| Code |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 13 |
| 15 |
| 1 |
| 13 |
| 8 |
| 13 |

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Here's the M code for it:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblCodes"]}[Content],
    mytable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(mytable, "Custom", each List.PositionOf(mytable[Code],[Code],Occurrence.All)),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    Custom1 = Table.Distinct(#"Extracted Values")
in
    Custom1
```